# differentiate two similar text using regex

Tags: regex, syntax, expression

I am trying to write a regex which can match the word

```
XXX_XXX.XXX_XXX
```

or

```
XXX_XX_XX.XXX_XX_X_XXX
```

or more similar patterns like this.
where `X` can be a letter or a number.
Basically, My regex should match a word consisting of numbers , dots and underscores but should not consist `_Struct.` 
.

Till now I am able to write

```
([\w.]+)
```

but it  matches with word consist of `_Struct.` too. What can be the right regex?

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_(?!Struct\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: Does it work? What is your regex engine?

Comment: No, it didnt work with XXX_XXX.XXX_XXX .

Comment: i am using regx101.com

Comment: So my regex works with XXX_XXX.XXX_XXX - https://regex101.com/r/QZicvt/1. Do you want to say this pattern should not necessarily match the whole string? Use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+_(?!Struct\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, see https://regex101.com/r/QZicvt/2

Comment: sorry, i explained my question wrong. I just updated the question.

Comment: `^\w+_(?!Struct\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w+$`? See https://regex101.com/r/QZicvt/3

Comment: Well, try also another one - `^(?:\w+_)?(?!Struct\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w+$` if the above is not what you need, see https://regex101.com/r/QZicvt/4

Comment: So, did any work for you?

Comment: What do you mean with `but should not consist _Struct.`? Could you add some examples that should match and some that souldn't?

Comment: with the help of @Wiktor and Nick  regex i was able to make following regex which fits to my requirement : (?!.*_Struct\.)^\s+(?:\w|\.)+$

Comment: So, it should always start with 1+ whitespaces? And can be `"  ......"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?!.*_Struct\.)^(?:\w|\.)+$`

This regex matches a word on a single line, as long as `_Struct.` doesn't appear in it.

- `(?!.*_Struct\.)` Assert `_Struct.` is not in the match.
- `^(?:\w|\.)+$` Between start and end of string, match any word character or a period, as many times as needed (but at least once).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VwrqFg/1/)

Comment: Do you think `...........` is a valid input? Besides, you missed a `^` anchor in the whole regex.

Comment: Good point. OP didn't specify it wasn't, but something like `(?!.*_Struct\.)^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?\.?)+$` would assert there's no leading or back-to-back periods / underscores. Updating answer.

Comment: Please never use patterns like `^(xY?)+$`, they lead to catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Good catch - going to have to keep thinking about this one then.